# Re.search not matching on same string

Tags: python, regex

I am using `re.search()`, and I'm trying to match a line from a file, however, when I'm expected a match it's not finding it. I've used the code before but now it's not working now and I am puzzled as to why.

I've tried using `.strip()`, still no luck

```
if re.search("/",line):
    new_line = line.split("/")
    for sub_design in seq_dict:
        match = re.search(sub_design, new_line[0])
        if match:
            seq_dict[match.group()] += 1
        else:
            print("sub design is")
            print(sub_design)
            print ("new line is")
            print(new_line[0])
```

The sub design contains 5 different strings, pulled from somewhere else.

I get these kind of prints :

The line variable would have the following string that it's read from a file:

```
hi_george_top[0].u_are_here/hi_george_sub/   something      great
```

sub design is

```
hi_george_top[0].u_are_here
```

new line is

```
hi_george_top[0].u_are_here
```

Comment: why not use `if '/' in line` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that would fix my issue @CorentinLimier

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, and what are those lines you append to the end of your question?

Comment: I'm trying look to see if there's a match, and increment the count in the dict.

Comment: At the end of the questions, those are results, of it going in the else statement even though it was supposed to match.

Comment: The question is, why did it not match? @olinox14

Comment: regex search is looking for the pattern in the first argument, your first argument is not a regex

Comment: try to change sub_design with smt like "\w+_\w+\[\d\].\w+" if i understand the problem correctly

Comment: You've also answered the problem, It was just trying to watch a pattern, but the "in" statement was more as what I should have done. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling that regex is not a solution here, I suggested in comment using the `in` statement instead.

```
line = "hi_george_top[0].u_are_here/hi_george_sub/   something      great"
seq_dict = {
    'bzhejf': 0,
    'eznjzfe' : 0,
    'zbjez' : 0,
    'hi_george_top[0]': 0
}
if '/' in line:
    new_line = line.split("/")
    for sub_design in seq_dict:
        if sub_design in new_line[0]:
            seq_dict[sub_design] += 1

print(seq_dict)
```

Displays :

```
{'bzhejf': 0, 'eznjzfe': 0, 'zbjez': 0, 'hi_george_top[0]': 1}
```

Comment: I just changed my code to exatly that, and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: The reason it did not work is not that regex is not a solution, but because regex here needed to be escaped. `match = re.search(re.escape(sub_design), new_line[0])` perfectly works...

Comment: Sure @olinox14, but it is kind of nonsense to escape the pattern then use a regex in that particular case don't you think ? You should always [Keep It Simple and Stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), that is why regex is not a solution here.

Comment: Of course, that's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer. But it's also good to explain why the previous code did not work...